# Prove the triangle is equilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

[image: imageshzu]

**HINTS ONLY please.**

This is very confusing right off the bat. My guess was that we show the angle $C, M, N$ are all $60^{\text{o}}.$

But I am having difficulty doing as as none of the givens have led me to any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** BCE and ACD are congruent.

Comment: (+1) I have been able to show this, but I am unable to use it. I mean it shows that $BM = AN = DN = ME$, but this doesnt seem very useful.

Comment: @Amad27: Ask yourself: What is the rigid movement that takes BCE to ACD? What does this movement do to C? To M? To CM?

Comment: I see what you are saying now. It turned right $60^{\text{o}}$ [can we prove this?] So $M$ maps to $N$ and $CM$ maps to $CN$. Hence, $CM$ maps to $CN$ and since the triangles are congruent (and not similar) $CM = CN$. The only issue now is $MN$. **EDIT** Since it maps on, the rotation is 60 degrees, and since the sides are also the same, the angles are all equal. Thus this proves the claim.

Comment: After proving BCE and ACD are congruent, the result of BM = AN = DN = ME can be of further use in proving BMC and ANC are congruent. After that, CM = CN. Result follows if you can further show that $\angle MCN = 60^0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: find a suitable rotation around $C$.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward (if a little messy) with coordinates.

Suppose without loss of generality that $A,B,C$ have Cartesian coordinates $(-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$; $(-1,0)$; and $(0,0)$ respectively. Let the side length of $ECD$ be $x$. Then you can find the coordinates for $D$ and $E$, and then for $M$ and $N$, and then use the distance formula to see that the three sides of the triangle under consideration are all equal (they all turn out to be $\sqrt{1+x+x^2}$).